# C# web and ftp crawler library

Tags: c#, web-crawler

I need a library (hopefully in C#!) which works as a web crawler to access HTTP files and FTP files. In principle, I'm happy with reading HTML, I want to extend it to PDF, WORD, etc..

I'm happy with a starter's open source software or at least any directions for documentation.

Comment: you might want to take a look at my implementation. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16975398/1610747

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [NCrawler](https://github.com/esbencarlsen/NCrawler) project

> Simple and very efficient multithreaded web crawler with pipeline based processing written in C#. Contains HTML, Text, PDF, and IFilter document processors and language detection(Google). Easy to add pipeline steps to extract, use and alter information.

Comment: +1: Very good suggestion, I'll give it some testing to see if it can help me. At first glance it seems so.

Comment: did this work for you ? cause I'm looking for similar one right now.

Comment: Yup, the project is quite nice.. I ended up using something else due t very specific requiremnts, but NCrawler does a very good job and it's well designed

Comment: Abot (http://code.google.com/p/abot/) is another flexible web crawler written in c#. Its licensing is also more commercial friendly.

Answer (score 1):

I have developed the Crawler Engine of the Crawler-Lib Framework. It is a workflow enabled crawler which can easily extended to do any kind of requests or even processing you want to have.

Here is the engine:
http://www.crawler-lib.net/crawler-lib-engine

Here are some Youtube Videos, showing how the Crawler-Lib engine works:
http://www.youtube.com/user/CrawlerLib

I know this project is not open source, but there is a free version.