# Simple web crawler in C#

Tags: c#, web-crawler

I have created a simple web crawler but I want to add the recursion function so that every page that is opened I can get the URLs in this page, but I have no idea how I can do that and I want also to include threads to make it faster.
Here is my code

```
namespace Crawler
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        String Rstring;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            WebRequest myWebRequest;
            WebResponse myWebResponse;
            String URL = textBox1.Text;

            myWebRequest =  WebRequest.Create(URL);
            myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse();//Returns a response from an Internet resource

            Stream streamResponse = myWebResponse.GetResponseStream();//return the data stream from the internet
                                                                       //and save it in the stream

            StreamReader sreader = new StreamReader(streamResponse);//reads the data stream
            Rstring = sreader.ReadToEnd();//reads it to the end
            String Links = GetContent(Rstring);//gets the links only
            
            textBox2.Text = Rstring;
            textBox3.Text = Links;
            streamResponse.Close();
            sreader.Close();
            myWebResponse.Close();




        }

        private String GetContent(String Rstring)
        {
            String sString="";
            HTMLDocument d = new HTMLDocument();
            IHTMLDocument2 doc = (IHTMLDocument2)d;
            doc.write(Rstring);
            
            IHTMLElementCollection L = doc.links;
           
            foreach (IHTMLElement links in  L)
            {
                sString += links.getAttribute("href", 0);
                sString += "/n";
            }
            return sString;
        }
```

Comment: Vote to close as not well scoped question. Please consider searching for "web crawler in C#" and refining you question to be more targeted.

Comment: You definitely don't want to use recursion as you won't be able to hold the state of the internet on the local stack.You could use a Stack as Tom suggested, but you should reverse the order in which you add AbsoluteUris to be crawled, else the nature of the stack will have you crawling from the bottom of the page and if you're going to write a crawler you need to have the retrieval behavior match a browser as closely as possible.  A Queue is a better choice.  A PriorityQueue is an even better one.

Comment: PriorityQueue

https://svn.arachnode.net/svn/arachnodenet/trunk/Structures/PriorityQueue.cs

UserName/Password: Public / Public

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I fixed your GetContent method as follow to get new links from crawled page:

```
public ISet<string> GetNewLinks(string content)
{
    Regex regexLink = new Regex("(?<=<a\\s*?href=(?:'|\"))[^'\"]*?(?=(?:'|\"))");

    ISet<string> newLinks = new HashSet<string>();    
    foreach (var match in regexLink.Matches(content))
    {
        if (!newLinks.Contains(match.ToString()))
            newLinks.Add(match.ToString());
    }

    return newLinks;
}
```

**Updated**

Fixed: regex should be regexLink. Thanks @shashlearner for pointing this out (my mistype).

Comment: Avoiding the problem of using regexes for HTML parsing but that fails to match quite a bit.

Comment: What is the regexLink here?

Comment: regex should be regexLink, thanks @shashlearner for pointing this out

Comment: What if I wanted to write a crawler to retrieve dynamic pages that are the result of a search?

Answer (score 8):

i have created something similar using [Reactive Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx).

https://github.com/Misterhex/WebCrawler

i hope it can help you.

```
Crawler crawler = new Crawler();

IObservable observable = crawler.Crawl(new Uri("http://www.codinghorror.com/"));

observable.Subscribe(onNext: Console.WriteLine, 
onCompleted: () => Console.WriteLine("Crawling completed"));
```

Comment: Wow! That's some pretty straightforward syntax. Is this multithreaded? Whatever the case, very easy to digest- Looks a lot like javascript.

Answer (score 2):

The following includes an answer/recommendation.

I believe you should use a `dataGridView` instead of a `textBox` as when you look at it in GUI it is easier to see the links (URLs) found.

You could change:

```
textBox3.Text = Links;
```

to

```
 dataGridView.DataSource = Links;
```

Now for the question, you haven't included:

```
using System.  "'s"
```

which ones were used, as it would be appreciated if I could get them as can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

From a design standpoint, I've written a few webcrawlers.  Basically you want to implement a Depth First Search using a Stack data structure.   You can use Breadth First Search also, but you'll likely come into stack memory issues.  Good luck.

Comment: I think the OP is asking for more detail.