# how to build web crawler using asp.net mvc3 and c#?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, lucene, web-crawler, lucene.net, robots.txt

I need to build the small search engine like Google using ASP.NET MVC 3. For this one I also need to build the web crawler which populate the data for search engine. In summary I need the following things:

How to build web crawler using Asp.net MVC3 with C#. I started to build some basic but I need to some guide, resource and books.

Using this web crawler, I poulate the data for search engine and apply the index on data using Lucene.Net. and I need to build small search engine which search the data populated by web crawler.

Please any body has any idea or resource or books. Please share with us.

Comment: you might want to take a look at my implementation. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16975398/1610747

Answer (score 15):

i created the web crawler and search using **Asp.net 4.0(Not any MVC) with C#**. i am going to post the details about it below.it may help somebody.
1.Create the table with following name and field.
Name:tblCrawlingData
Fiels:Id type:Int,Url type:text ,Title type:text,Contents type:text
2.I am using Linq to sql for database. so please make linq to sql setting your self.
3. i am using Lucene.net library indexing. Lucene.Net Class(Lucene.Net.dll)

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.IO;
    using DataManager.BOL;
    using Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard;
    using Lucene.Net.Index;
    using Lucene.Net.Store;
    using Lucene.Net.Search;
    using Lucene.Net.Documents;
    using Lucene.Net.QueryParsers;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    namespace AryaSearch.LuceneSearch{
    public class LuceneSearch
    {
        //Total Records
        private static long _totalResutl = 0;
        //Total Time taken to retrive the record
        private static double _totalTime = 0;
        // Full physical path of lucene index directory.
        private static string _luceneDir = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, "IndexStorage");
        private static FSDirectory _directoryTemp;

    private static FSDirectory _directory
    {
        get
        {
            if (_directoryTemp == null)
                _directoryTemp = FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo(_luceneDir));
            if (IndexWriter.IsLocked(_directoryTemp))
                IndexWriter.Unlock(_directoryTemp);
            var lockFilePath = Path.Combine(_luceneDir, "write.lock");
            if (File.Exists(lockFilePath))
                File.Delete(lockFilePath);

            return _directoryTemp;
        }
    }


    private static void _addToLuceneIndex(CrawlingData spiderData, IndexWriter writer)
    {
        // remove older index entry
        var searchQuery = new TermQuery(new Term("Id", spiderData.Id.ToString()));
        writer.DeleteDocuments(searchQuery);
        //add new index entry
        var doc = new Document();
        // add lucene fields mapped to db fields
        doc.Add(new Field("Id", spiderData.Id.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
        doc.Add(new Field("Url", spiderData.Url, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
        doc.Add(new Field("Title", spiderData.Title, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
        doc.Add(new Field("Contents", spiderData.Contents, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));

        // add entry to index
        writer.AddDocument(doc);
    }



    public static void AddUpdateLuceneIndex(IEnumerable<CrawlingData> spiderDatas)
    {
        // initialize  lucene
        var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30);
        using (var writer = new IndexWriter(_directory, analyzer, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED))
        {
            // add data to lucene search index (replaces older entry if any) by calling method _addToLuceneIndex
            foreach (var spiderData in spiderDatas)
                _addToLuceneIndex(spiderData, writer);

            // close all method and handlers
            analyzer.Close();
            //writer.Close();
            writer.Dispose();


        }
    }


    public static void AddUpdateLuceneIndex(CrawlingData spiderDatas)
    {
        AddUpdateLuceneIndex(new List<CrawlingData> { spiderDatas });
    }


    public static void ClearLuceneIndexRecord(int record_id)
    {
        //intialize lucene classs
        var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30);
        using (var writer = new IndexWriter(_directory, analyzer, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED))
        {
            // remove the older or deleted entry from lucene index
            var searchQuery = new TermQuery(new Term("Id", record_id.ToString()));
            writer.DeleteDocuments(searchQuery);

            //close the handlers
            analyzer.Close();
            //writer.Close();
            writer.Dispose();
        }
    }


    public static bool ClearLuceneIndex()
    {
        try
        {
            //intialize lucene classs
            var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30);
            using (var writer = new IndexWriter(_directory, analyzer, true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED))
            {
                // remove all older index entries
                writer.DeleteAll();
                //close handlers
                analyzer.Close();
                //writer.Close();
                writer.Dispose();
            }


        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }



    public static void Optimize()
    {
        //intialize lucene classs
        var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30);
        using (var writer = new IndexWriter(_directory, analyzer, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED))
        {
            //close all handlers
            analyzer.Close();
            writer.Optimize();
            //writer.Close();
            writer.Dispose();
        }


    }


    private static CrawlingData _mapLuceneDocumentToData(Document doc)
    {
        try
        {
            return new CrawlingData
            {
                Id = Convert.ToInt32(doc.Get("Id")),
                Url = doc.Get("Url"),
                Title = doc.Get("Title"),
                Contents = doc.Get("Contents").Substring(0,500)+"...",
                Total= _totalResutl,
                Time=_totalTime
            };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }

    }



    private static IEnumerable<CrawlingData> _mapLuceneToDataList(IEnumerable<Document> hits)
    {

        return hits.Select(_mapLuceneDocumentToData).ToList();
    }



    private static IEnumerable<CrawlingData> _mapLuceneToDataList(IEnumerable<ScoreDoc> hits, IndexSearcher searcher)
    {

        return hits.Select(hit => _mapLuceneDocumentToData(searcher.Doc(hit.Doc))).ToList();

    }



    private static Query parseQuery(string searchQuery, QueryParser parser)
    {
        Query query;
        try
        {
            query = parser.Parse(searchQuery.Trim());
        }
        catch (ParseException)
        {
            query = parser.Parse(QueryParser.Escape(searchQuery.Trim()));
        }

        return query;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<CrawlingData> _search(string searchQuery, string searchField = "")
    {
        //validate the input
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchQuery.Replace("*", "").Replace("?", "")))
            return new List<CrawlingData>();
        // set up lucene searcher
        using (var searcher = new IndexSearcher(_directory, false))
        {
            //when Lucene gets more than 1000 search results,
            //it becomes increasingly slow, so you'd want to limit it to a number which is relevant in your case
            //var hits_limit = 1000;
            var hits_limit = 10;
            //initialize the lucene class.
            var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30);
            // search by single field
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchField))
            {
                var parser = new QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, searchField, analyzer);
                var query = parseQuery(searchQuery, parser);
                //var hits = searcher.Search(query, hits_limit).ScoreDocs;
                Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();                
                var hitsTemp = searcher.Search(query, hits_limit);
                watch.Stop();
                _totalTime = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000;
                _totalTime = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(_totalTime), 2);
                _totalResutl = hitsTemp.TotalHits;
                var hits = hitsTemp.ScoreDocs;
                var results = _mapLuceneToDataList(hits, searcher);// _mapLuceneSearchResultsToDataList(hits, searcher);
                analyzer.Close();
                //searcher.Close();
                searcher.Dispose();
                return results;
            }
            // search by multiple fields (ordered by RELEVANCE). you can search order here.
            else
            {
                var parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser
                (Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, new[] { "Id", "Url", "Title",  "Contents" }, analyzer);
                var query = parseQuery(searchQuery, parser);
                Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew(); 
                var hitsTemp = searcher.Search(query, null, hits_limit, Sort.RELEVANCE);
                watch.Stop();
                _totalTime = (float)watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000;
                _totalTime = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(_totalTime), 2);
                _totalResutl = hitsTemp.TotalHits;
                Sort.RELEVANCE).ScoreDocs;
                var hits = hitsTemp.ScoreDocs;
                var results = _mapLuceneToDataList(hits, searcher); 
                analyzer.Close();
                //searcher.Close();
                searcher.Dispose();
                return results;
            }
        }
    }



    public static IEnumerable<CrawlingData> Search(string input, string fieldName = "")
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) return new List<CrawlingData>();

        var terms = input.Trim().Replace("-", " ").Split(' ')
            .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).Select(x => x.Trim() + "*");
        input = string.Join(" ", terms);

        return _search(input, fieldName);
    }



    public static IEnumerable<CrawlingData> SearchDefault(string input, string fieldName = "")
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) ? new List<CrawlingData>() : _search(input, fieldName);
    }



    public static IEnumerable<CrawlingData> GetAllIndexRecords()
    {

        if (!System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(_luceneDir).Any()) return new List<CrawlingData>();


        var searcher = new IndexSearcher(_directory, false);
        var reader = IndexReader.Open(_directory, false);
        var docs = new List<Document>();
        var term = reader.TermDocs();
        while (term.Next()) docs.Add(searcher.Doc(term.Doc));
        reader.Dispose();
        //searcher.Close();
        searcher.Dispose();
        return _mapLuceneToDataList(docs);
    }

     }
    }
```

4.Crawling Function. i am using HtmlAgilityPack.dll for parsing html text.
Crawling (Default.aspx)

```
    <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <div class="crawlText">
        <h2 class="customAlignMent">
            <font color="red">A</font><font color="blue">R</font><font color="black">Y</font><font
                color="green">A</font>
        </h2>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCrawl" runat="server" TextMode="SingleLine" Width="60%"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Button ID="btnCrawling" runat="server" Text="Start Crawling" CssClass="submitButton"
                    OnClick="btnCrawling_Click" OnClientClick="javascript:ClearOldText();"/>
                <p>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="txtCrawlUrl" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*Required!"
                        ControlToValidate="txtCrawl" CssClass="failureNotification" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="txtCrawlUrlR" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Valid Url!"
                        ControlToValidate="txtCrawl" CssClass="failureNotification" ValidationExpression="^(ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\'\/\\\+&amp;%\$#_]*)?$"
                        Display="Dynamic"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                </p>
                <p>
                    &nbsp;</p>
                <div id="showExtractConetent" runat="server" class="ExtractContent">
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1"
            DisplayAfter="5">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                <div id="divStatusID" runat="server">
                    <p class="textEntry">
                        please wait,processing....</p>
                    <asp:Image ID="ajaxloading" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Image/loading.gif" AlternateText="processing...." />
                </div>
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        function ClearOldText() {

            $get("<%=showExtractConetent.ClientID%>").innerHTML = '';
        }
    -->
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

**Code Behind File**

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Text;
using DataManager.BOL;
using DataManager.BLL;
using AryaSearch.LuceneSearch;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btnCrawling_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        showExtractConetent.InnerHtml = string.Empty;
        Webcrawling(txtCrawl.Text.Trim());   
    }

    private void Webcrawling(string url)
    {
        CrawlingData cData = new CrawlingData();
        string _requestUrl = url.Trim();
        string _encodingType = "utf-8";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_requestUrl);            
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        request.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 3;
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/6.0 (MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; Arya.NET Robot)";
        request.KeepAlive = true;            request.Timeout = 15 * 1000;

        System.Net.HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        showExtractConetent.InnerHtml = ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription;
        showExtractConetent.InnerHtml += "<br/>";
        _encodingType = GetEncodingType(response);
        System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader
                                       (response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding(_encodingType));
        // Read the content.
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        ISet<string> Links = ExtractLinkFromContent(responseFromServer);//gets the links only
        //Display the title
        string pageTitle = getPageTitle(responseFromServer);
        showExtractConetent.InnerHtml = "<h1 class=bold>" + pageTitle + "</h1>";
        // Display the content.
        //Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
        showExtractConetent.InnerHtml += StripHtmlTags(responseFromServer);
        showExtractConetent.InnerHtml += "<br/>";
        //Dispaly the Links of all page.
        string urls = string.Empty;
        foreach (string l in Links)
        {
            urls += l.ToString() + "<br/>";


        }
        showExtractConetent.InnerHtml += "<h1 class=bold>Links of Pages</h1>";
        showExtractConetent.InnerHtml += urls;
        cData.Url = _requestUrl;
        cData.Title = pageTitle;
        cData.Contents = StripHtmlTags(responseFromServer);
        var dbstatus = DataManagerBLL.InsertCrawlingData(cData);
        //Create Lucene Index For This Data.
        if (dbstatus>0)
        {
            cData.Id = (int)dbstatus;
            LuceneSearch.AddUpdateLuceneIndex(cData);
        }
        // Clean up the streams.
        reader.Close();
        //dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();


    }

    private ISet<string> ExtractLinkFromContent(String content)
    {
        Regex regexLink = new Regex("(?<=<a\\s*?href=(?:'|\"))[^'\"]*?(?=(?:'|\"))");

        ISet<string> newLinks = new HashSet<string>();
        foreach (var match in regexLink.Matches(content))
        {
            if (!newLinks.Contains(match.ToString()))
                newLinks.Add(match.ToString());
        }

        return newLinks;
    }
    private string GetEncodingType(HttpWebResponse response)
    {
        string pageCharset = string.Empty;
        if (response.ContentType != string.Empty)
        {
            pageCharset = response.ContentEncoding;
        }

        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(pageCharset) ? pageCharset : "utf-8";

    }
    private string StripHtmlTags(string html)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(html))
            return string.Empty;
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
        doc.LoadHtml(html);
        doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                .Where(n => n.Name == "script" || n.Name == "style" || n.Name == "#comment")
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(n => n.Remove());
        //Read the body content only.
        HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("form");
        HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("a");
        HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("img");
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode bodyNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode formNode = bodyNode.SelectSingleNode("//form");
        HtmlNodeCollection tags = bodyNode.SelectNodes("//form | //input | //select | //textarea");
        if (tags != null && tags.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < tags.Count; i++)
                tags.Remove(i);
        }
        if (bodyNode != null)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl();
            div.InnerText = bodyNode.InnerText;
            string tempdivtext = div.InnerText;
            //tempdivtext=tempdivtext.Replace(formNode.InnerText,"");
            tempdivtext = tempdivtext.Replace("\r\n", string.Empty);
            tempdivtext = tempdivtext.Replace("\n", string.Empty);
            tempdivtext = tempdivtext.Replace("\t", string.Empty);
            return tempdivtext.Trim().ToString();
        }

        return doc.DocumentNode.InnerText;
    }

    private string getPageTitle(string html)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(html))
            return string.Empty;
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
        doc.LoadHtml(html);
        //Read the body content only.
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode titleNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//title");
        if (titleNode != null)
            return titleNode.InnerText;

        return doc.DocumentNode.InnerText;

    }
}
```

Now For Search
**Search.aspx**

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Search.aspx.cs" Inherits="Search" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="Server">
    <div class="SearchHeadingText">
        <h2 class="customAlignMent">
            <font color="red">A</font><font color="blue">R</font><font color="black">Y</font><font
                color="green">A</font>
        </h2>

           <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelForSearch" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" TextMode="SingleLine" Width="70%"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnAryaSearch" runat="server" Text="Arya Search" 
                        CssClass="submitButton" onclick="btnAryaSearch_Click" />

                    <p>
                        &nbsp;</p>
                    <div id="showExtractConetent" runat="server" class="SearchResult">
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgressSearch" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanelForSearch"
                DisplayAfter="5">
                <ProgressTemplate>
                    <div id="divStatusID" runat="server">
                        <p class="textEntry">
                            please wait,Searching....</p>
                        <asp:Image ID="ajaxloading" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Image/loading.gif" AlternateText="processing...." />
                    </div>
                </ProgressTemplate>
            </asp:UpdateProgress>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

**Code behind file search.aspx.cs**

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using DataManager.BOL;
using DataManager.BLL;
using System.Text;

public partial class Search : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btnAryaSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string input = txtSearch.Text.Trim();
        string fieldName = string.Empty;
        //fieldName = "Title";
        List<CrawlingData> result = DataManagerBLL.searchResult(input, fieldName);
        //Build the text format using string builder to dispaly the result
        StringBuilder resultText = new StringBuilder();
        if (result != null && result.Count > 0)
        {
            resultText.AppendFormat("<p>About {0} results ({1} seconds)</p>", result[0].Total.ToString(), result[0].Time.ToString());
            foreach (CrawlingData s in result)
            {
                resultText.AppendFormat("<a href='{0}' target='{1}'>{2}</a>", s.Url, "_blank", s.Title);
                resultText.AppendFormat("<br/>");
                resultText.AppendFormat("<em class=\"customlink\">{0}</em>", s.Url);
                resultText.AppendFormat("<br/>");
                resultText.AppendFormat("<span class=\"searchContent\"><em>{0}<em></span>", s.Contents);
                resultText.AppendFormat("<br/><br/>");

            }
            showExtractConetent.InnerHtml = resultText.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            showExtractConetent.InnerText = "No results found";
        }

    }
}
```

**Linq to Sql Business Object**

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
namespace DataManager.BOL
{


public class CrawlingData
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Contents { get; set; }
    public long Total { get; set; }
    public double Time { get; set; }
}

}
```

**Linq to Sql Business Logic(Crud opetion)**

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using DataManager.BOL;
using DataManagerDAL;
using AryaSearch.LuceneSearch;
namespace DataManager.BLL
{
    public static class DataManagerBLL
    {
        public static long InsertCrawlingData(CrawlingData cdata)
        {
            long lastInsertId = 0;
            try
            {
                using (DataClassesDataContext _db = new DataClassesDataContext())
                {


                    tblCrawlingData dataUpdate = _db.tblCrawlingDatas.Where(c => c.Url.ToLower() == cdata.Url.ToLower()).Take(1).SingleOrDefault();
                    if (dataUpdate == null)
                    {
                        tblCrawlingData data = new tblCrawlingData();
                        data.Id = cdata.Id;
                        data.Url = cdata.Url;
                        data.Title = cdata.Title;
                        data.Contents = cdata.Contents;
                        _db.tblCrawlingDatas.InsertOnSubmit(data);
                        _db.SubmitChanges();
                        lastInsertId =data.Id;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //data.Id = cdata.Id;
                        dataUpdate.Url = cdata.Url;
                        dataUpdate.Title = cdata.Title;
                        dataUpdate.Contents = cdata.Contents;
                        _db.SubmitChanges();
                        lastInsertId = dataUpdate.Id;
                    }
                    return lastInsertId;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {


                return 0;
            }
        }

        public static bool UpdateCrawlingData(CrawlingData cdata)
        {
            try
            {
                using (DataClassesDataContext _db = new DataClassesDataContext())
                {
                    //tblCrawlingData data = new tblCrawlingData();
                    tblCrawlingData data=_db.tblCrawlingDatas.Where(c => c.Id == cdata.Id).Take(1).SingleOrDefault();                    
                    if (data == null)
                        return false;
                    data.Id = cdata.Id;
                    data.Url = cdata.Url;
                    data.Title = cdata.Title;
                    data.Contents = cdata.Contents;
                    _db.SubmitChanges();
                    LuceneSearch.Optimize();    
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }


        public static List<CrawlingData> searchResult(string input, string fieldName)
        {
            LuceneSearch.Optimize();            
            return LuceneSearch.Search(input, fieldName).ToList();

        }


    }
}
```

*if any body has any problem. please contact me. i worked very hard to make this. so please if some get help from it, please vote me.
thanks*

Comment: If you're going to post such a massive wall of text, at least check that it's formatted properly.

Comment: i improved the formatting. can you tell me why do some point unneccessary deducting from reputation ? how can i complain about this?

Comment: This post hasn't been downvoted, so you shouldn't have lost points for it. The question was most likely downvoted because it's much too broad, I'm actually surprised it wasn't closed.  You can complain on [meta.se], but complaining about downvotes rarely helps.

Comment: i did not get any email to complain. how do i complain about downvotes?

Comment: As I said, complain on [meta.se]. But it's highly unlikely you'll get anywhere.

Comment: this is the complete source code. you only just need to make one database table.create table with following details.table name:tblCrawlingData, Fiels:Id type:Int,Url type:text ,Title type:text,Contents type:text

Comment: Wow that's a lot of codes. +1 for example! I have a question. What if the page has a dynamic search and each time there is a result I would like the crawler to crawl the page?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a look at the documentation/source of one of the open source crawlers? [Apache Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/) for example is written in Java so it shouldn't be too hard to read if you are developing in C#.

You could also try to use Google on your own...

[Nutch Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/FrontPage) and some [interesting papers about Nutch](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/AcademicArticles).

See Wikipedia for a [list of open source crawlers.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler#Open-source_crawlers)