# Crawl and Extract content from website

Tags: c#, .net, web-crawler

I want to extract data from a e-commerce website (for ex- www.ebay.com). Some of the information that I want to extract are: Product name, description, price , detail description, images links, the seller information.

There is DownloadString(string URL) method in webclient class , using that I can get source code of HTML page, but I want to extract information about all the products (For example I want product information about all products under Electronics section), So How can I achieve that?

Do I need to change URL every time or is there any way using that I can crawl complete website?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3962281/279982

Answer (score 2):

You should **not** crawl their websites and instead use their [WebService API](https://go.developer.ebay.com/)

Comment: Targeted website does not expose any API :-(

Comment: Ahh I was under the impression that you wanted to crawl ebay, sorry.